# scikit learn poly kernel and gamma value?

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn

I am going to use scikit SVC with polynomial kernel in the following format: (1 + xTn.xm)^4. 
Meaning (one plus the product of xTn.xm) with degree 4. xTn is the xn value that is transposed.
When I look into the scikit documentation they specify the parameters for SVC:

> 

```
    degree : int, optional (default=3)
 |      Degree of kernel function.
 |      It is significant only in 'poly' and 'sigmoid'.
 |  
 |  gamma : float, optional (default=0.0)
 |      Kernel coefficient for 'rbf' and 'poly'.
 |      If gamma is 0.0 then 1/n_features will be used instead.
 |  
 |  coef0 : float, optional (default=0.0)
 |      Independent term in kernel function.
 |      It is only significant in 'poly' and 'sigmoid'.
```

The parameter "degree" is relevant and I should use 4.
The parameter coef0 is relevant and I should use the value 1. Is it correct?
The gamma is very unclear in the "Poly" case. Which value should I use for gamma??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the libsvm documentation: `(gamma * u'* v + coef0)^degree` (scikit-learn is based on it for the SVC model). A pull-request to improve the documentation is always welcomed :)

Comment: Thanks! In that case I should use gamma = 1 because I do not need it.

Comment: In the user guide, this formular is already shown. See http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/svm.html#svm-kernels.

And I think we decided to not put all the details in the docstring but rather put this comment in there:

    For details on the precise mathematical formulation of
    the provided
    kernel functions and how `gamma`, `coef0` and `degree` affecteach,
    see the corresponding section in the narrative documentation:
    :ref:`svm_kernels`

Comment: I think this was a mistake. The docstring should explain the meaning of all the parameters and the formulas is the most concise way to do it.